# Can ESP32 node MCU read 5V input?

Tags: voltage, sensor, esp32

So I've got a [YFS201](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/yf-s201_sea.pdf) sensor which I was using with a Arduino Nano. Now I am employing a ESP32 Node MCU which uses 3.3V logic. I'll be powering the ESP32 with 5V through the Vin pin. I'll be powering the YFS201 with the same 5V supply and ground, but I'd take the pulse signal into the digital I/O of ESP32. Would the pulse signal be at 5V. Would ESP32 be able to handle 5V pulse? Would it be better to reduce the voltage to 3.3V by using a resistor in the path, or should I use some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output signal voltage of YF-S201 is 5V. The GPIOs of ESP32 are not 5V tolerant. You should reduce the signal level to 3.3V. You can use a resistor voltage divider or a logic-level converter.

Comment: I would also be using a 5V 16x2 I2C LCD. Would its SCL SDA be able to communicate with  the ESP32 without a voltage divide or logic level convertor?

Comment: No, you need a logic level converter for them too. e.g. [PCA9517](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2205241716_NXP-Semicon-PCA9517DP-118_C2652381.pdf)